# WinRT XAML AppBarButton UI style issue on App Culture changed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have two custom App Bar buttons as shown below in the attached screenshot. The styles for these buttons are written in App.xaml page. The button styles are getting distorted when the app/device language is changed. On comparing and analysing different builds I have prepared earlier, I found that the styles were working perfectly before I introduced the below Language Culture override change in App.xaml

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(currentAppLanguage);
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = ci.Name;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
```

**Where the value of currentAppLanguage is the language of App/Device accordingly**

This culture update is important, since a few controls like Datepicker etc., are relying on this Culture change to get translated based on selected Language.

Erroneous:

[image]

Correct:

[image]

The page is working fine with English culture. But when the user updates the language through Application or on the Phone, the button style breaks.

I am overriding the primary language culture when the app loads, based on the selected language. Would it be possible for the culture change to impact XAML styles and elements?

Any suggestions would greatly help.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the app bar button control and the style

> Button:

```
    <AppBarButton 
        Visibility="{Binding CanReject, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
        x:Name="abReject"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Height="62"
        Width="62"
        Style="{StaticResource RejectAppBarButtonStyle}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding LoadedApproval.ApprovalState, Converter={StaticResource StringComparerToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Pending}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource DictationGray}" 
        BorderThickness="2"
        Foreground="White"
        Background="{StaticResource ApprovalRejectRed}"
        Margin="0,0">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                   <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="Rejecting" UseTransitions="True"/>
                   </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
             </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     </AppBarButton>
```

> Style:

```
<Style x:Key="RejectAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton" >
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <RepositionThemeAnimation TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointOverOverlay"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ApprovalRejectRed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse 
                        x:Name="OuterEllipse"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="2" 
                        UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse 
                            x:Name="BackgroundEllipse"
                            Height="{Binding Height, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticOperationConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.78, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            Width="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticOperationConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.78, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            UseLayoutRounding="True">
                        </Ellipse>
                        <Ellipse 
                            x:Name="PointOverOverlay"
                            Opacity="0"
                            Height="{Binding Height, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticOperationConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.78, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            Width="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticOperationConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.78, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
                            Fill="{StaticResource PointOverShade}"
                            UseLayoutRounding="True">
                        </Ellipse>
                        <Path 
                            x:Name="Content"
                            Data="M1.5,1.5 L40.392,40.391 M1.5,40.391 L40.392,1.5" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                            Stretch="Uniform" 
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Round" 
                            Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            StrokeThickness="3" 
                            StrokeLineJoin="Round" 
                            Height="{Binding Height, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticOperationConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.33, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            Width="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticOperationConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.33, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what does your style look like?

Comment: I don't think changing the culture will impact XAML styles and elements, can you post your XAML code the style of this two buttons? It's sounds like a strange problem here. Did you put your style in resource file?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT. Thanks for the reply. I have added the code above in my post. The reason why I'm pointing towards culture is because the build version without this culture update is working fine for all the languages.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Would it be possible to add culture override only to specific pages or just switch the culture between pages?

Comment: @Sriram, I can't 100% reproduce your problem, I completed the converter part by myself, but there are some static resources like "{StaticResource PointOverShade}" which I can't know. And your posted C# code, you mean this code is in the App.xaml.cs file? Perhaps in the `OnLaunched` method? Is that possible that you have a resource file where you define your static resources, and when you change culture, this resource file is changed also? It's so strange, I can't figure out why, I'm so sorry.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Grace. The C# code I added is placed on OnLaunched inside App.xaml.cs file. When the device language or App's language are changed, the app would required to be restarted. When restarting the app, I would set the culture using that code. Resource files contains the strings used throughout the app. There are around 6 resource files each supporting a specific language. Based on the language, the specific resource file would be used. This would also happen during App launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find where the issue occurred. That was in the converter class **ArithmeticOperationConverter**. Below is the convert method.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (parameter == null)
        return value;

    Double val;
    Double param;

    if (Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val) && Double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out param))
    {
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case (ArithmeticMode.Addition):
                return val + param;
            case (ArithmeticMode.Subtratction):
                return val - param;
            case (ArithmeticMode.Multiplication):
                return val * param;
            case (ArithmeticMode.Division):
                return val / param;
            default:
                return val;
        }
    }
    else
        return value;
}
```

Here the TryParse() method that parses the parameter value in if condition was causing the problem. The parameter string value passed (for example) was "0.78" and the outcome was 78.0 instead of 0.78 causing the distortion in UI. **This was happening because of the Culture variance between number notations**. I added **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture** argument to the TryParse() method and it fixed the problem.

Thanks for you suggestions @GraceFeng-MSFT